# Select many CheckBox on GridPanel Ext.Net (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, ext.net, gridpanel

How to select Rows on GridPanel using ext.net Library on ASP.NET.
When i put this code on Page_Load event, it's work fine :

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      RowSelectionModel sm = gridRolesPermission.GetSelectionModel() as RowSelectionModel;
        sm.SelectedRows.Add(new SelectedRow(1));
        sm.SelectedRows.Add(new SelectedRow(2));
    }
```

but when i would to select CheckBoxs on Ajax event, it's not working !

```
  [DirectMethod]
        public void FillPermissionForSelectedRole()
        {
        RowSelectionModel sm = gridRolesPermission.GetSelectionModel() as RowSelectionModel;
        sm.SelectedRows.Add(new SelectedRow(1));
        sm.SelectedRows.Add(new SelectedRow(2));
        }
```

On view :

```
....
<Listeners>
<Command Handler="App.direct.FillPermissionForSelectedRole();" />
</Listeners>
...
```

Any Help Please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to resolve this probleme i should add this line to upadate modifications :

```
sm.UpdateSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example,when u click the button(directMethod button),a pamatercollection sent to the server called `CheckboxSelectionModel1` .on server side, u can get the this parameter collection like this.

```
string hh= HttpContext.Current.Request["CheckboxSelectionModel1"];
```

*CheckboxSelectionModel1 is the model name of the grid on your example.

in your case like that

```
[DirectMethod]
        public void FillPermissionForSelectedRole()
        {
 string hh= HttpContext.Current.Request["CheckboxSelectionModel1"];

        }
```

string hh should be something like this depents on the what u checked on grid.

```
"[{"RecordID":5,"RowIndex":5},{"RecordID":7,"RowIndex":7},{"RecordID":3,"RowIndex":3}]"
```

later u can desrialize  this string and get the RecordID something like this

```
    var rw = JSON.Deserialize<Row[]>(hh);
    string txt = "";
    foreach (var item in rw)
    {
        txt += item.RecordID;
    }
```

and the row class

```
public  class Row{
            public string RecordID { get; set; }
            public string RowIndex { get; set; }

        }
```